# Prove $x' \neq x$ using Peano axioms

Tags: logic, peano-axioms

I am looking at Edmund Landau, *Foundation of analysis* and do not agree with is proof of Theorem 2 part 2. I put the pages here for easy reference (http://pbrd.co/1y89p7b and  http://pbrd.co/1y89A2s).

Problem I have with Landau, is theorem 2,  part 2  does not prove the theorem (I think). 
Theorem is \begin{equation}x’ \neq x\end{equation} 
1. He assumes the theorem and goes on with the result.

2. Another issue, if we assume successor function is injective does not mean that x and suc(x) can be one and the same in value. Lastly, injection is a big assumption. Axiom 2 “exactly 1” but does not say mutually exclusive.
3. I have a separate proof via contradiction. Basically I assume x’ = x and using axiom 4, disprove it as below:

Assume
\begin{equation}x’ = x\end{equation} 
Also,from Axiom 4
\begin{equation} 
x' = y' => x = y
\end{equation} 
This leads to the following contradiction from our assumption and 1st part of axiom 4 that:
\begin{equation}
x = y'
\end{equation} 
This cannot be true because of part 2 of axiom 4 which says:
\begin{equation}
x = y
\end{equation} 
Since the axiom must hold true making our assumption as incorrect. Hence the theorem is proved i.e.
\begin{equation} 
x' \neq x
\end{equation} 
Would appreciate any insights. Is it because this book is a translation of the original german book and someone messed it up ?

Comment: It is a proof by induction (Axiom 5). Looks fine.

Comment: No. How does he assume the theorem in the first line. Induction is to prove it for all natural numbers at the end. Please look at box in image http://pbrd.co/1yBN0hC . If he is using injection from axiom 4, please look at my comment 2 in the question where I feel injection argument will fail as well.

Comment: I had looked at it already. He does not assume it. He has *defined* what looks like Gothic $M$ to be the set of all $x$ such that $x'\ne x$. So *by definition* if $x\in M$ then $x'\ne x$. What he does is to prove using Axiom 5 that $M$ is all of $N$.

Comment: Thank You. Obviously, I a newbie. Any comments on my proof via contradiction. I do not see Gothic M where x′≠x Axiom 5 just mentions x' and x are both part of the set gothic M. It does not mention anything about(in)equality. Any book better than Landau.. I am trying to self study number theory before analysis.

Comment: It is very late here. Maybe tomorrow if things are not yet clear I can go into detail about your argument. That argument does not mention Axiom 5, at least not explicitly. But we **cannot prove** $x'\ne x$ from the first four axioms. For let $W$ consist of the positive integers together with a new object $B$. On $W$ define successor by $x'=x+1$ if $x$ is a natural number, and $B'=B$. Then every one of the first four axioms is satisfied. Axiom 5 is not, and there is an object which is its own successor.

Comment: As to not seeing it, look at Theorem 2. The first line of the proof defines  $M$ as the set of all $x$ such that $x'\ne x$.  Number Theory is a very different subject from analysis, and is not really needed for analysis. This Landau book is not number theory, it is a painfully detailed exposition of the basics of analysis. Very nice book, but you will find modern ones more palatable. Everybody seems to like Spivak's Calculus.

Comment: There are also nice online lecture notes by Tao. You will find other recommendations on MSE and elsewhere.

Comment: I'm not sure that your purported proof by contradiction will work ... Assuming $x'=x$, from $x'=y' \rightarrow x=y$ you conclude with : $x=y'$. But due to the fact thaat $x=y$, we have $y=y'$, and this is consistent with your assumption that $x'=x$, with no contradiction ...

Answer (score 2):

*I'll try only to recap André's comments regarding Landau's proof* : there are no mistakes in the book's translation from the original german edition.

**Theorem 2** [page 3] : $x' \ne x$

*Note* : with more details, Landau will prove : for all $x$, $(x' \ne x)$.

The proof is by *induction*; thus, we have to review [[page 2](https://books.google.it/books?id=DvIJBAAAQBAJ&pg=PA2)] :

> **Axiom 5** (Axiom of Induction) : Let there be given a set $\mathfrak M$ of natural numbers, with the following properties :
>
> > I) $1$ belongs to $\mathfrak M$
> >
> > II) if $x$ belongs to $\mathfrak M$ so does $x'$.
>
> Then $\mathfrak M$ contains all the natural numbers.

Now for the proof of **Th.2** :

> Let $\mathfrak M$ the set of all [natural numbers] $x$ for which $x' \ne x$ hold true.

First, we have to prove the *basis* of induction :

> I) By Axiom 1 and Axiom 3 : $1' \ne 1$; therefore $1$ belongs to $\mathfrak M$.

We have :

> **Axiom 1** [page 2] : $1$ is a natural number.

Thus, $1$ is a "candidate" for being one of $x$ belonging to $\mathfrak M$.

> **Axiom 3** [page 2] : We always have : $x' \ne 1$.

This means that : for all [natural numbers] $x$, $(x' \ne 1)$; thus, being $1$ a natural number, we have : $1' \ne 1$.

So far, we have proved step I) of **Axiom 5** : $1$ belongs to the set $\mathfrak M$ of all [natural numbers] $x$ for which $x' \ne x$ hold true.

Now for the *induction step* :

> II) If $x$ belongs to $\mathfrak M$, then $x' \ne x$, and hence by Theorem 1, $(x')' \ne x'$, so that $x'$ belongs to $\mathfrak M$.

This is the "standard" *induction step* : assume $A(n)$ and prove $A(n+1)$. In Landau's proof :

> assume $x' \ne x$ and prove $(x')' \ne x'$

and this is proved according to :

> **Theorem 1** [page 3] : if $x \ne y$, then $x' \ne y'$,

with $x'$ in place of $x$ and $x$ in place of $y$.

*Conclusion* :

- Let $\mathfrak M$ the set of all [natural numbers] $x$ for which $x' \ne x$ hold true.
- By I) we have proved that : $1$ belongs to $\mathfrak M$.
- By II) we have proved that : if $x$ belongs to $\mathfrak M$, then $x'$ belongs to $\mathfrak M$.
- Now we can apply **Axiom 5** to conclude with :

> > $\mathfrak M$ contains all the natural numbers,

which amounts to saying that :

> for all $x$ , $x \in \mathfrak M$, i.e. for all [natural numbers] $x$, $x' \ne x$ hold true.

---

Note that Landau follows quite closely Peano's original formulation; see :

- Giuseppe Peano, [Arithmetices principia, nova methodo exposita](https://archive.org/stream/arithmeticespri00peangoog#page/n6/mode/2up) (1889: The principles of arithmetic presented by a new method), in Jean van Heijenoort, [From Frege to Gödel : A Source Book in Mathematical Logic](https://books.google.it/books?id=v4tBTBlU05sC&pg=PA94) (1967), page 94.

Answer (score 0):

Base Case:

$$0' \ne 0$$

That is an axiom: nothing precedes $0$.

Inductive case:

$$\begin{align}
x' \ne x & \Rightarrow x'' \ne x' &\text{Inductive Statement} \\
x'' = x' &\Rightarrow x' = x  & \text{Contrapositive} \\
y' = x' &\Rightarrow y = x  & \text{by letting y =  x'} \\
\end{align}$$

That is also an axiom:  Successor is injective (invertible).

And induction is itself an axiom.